# How to test function in jest which is not returning any value in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, unit-testing, jestjs

Am new to Jest testing env. I need to write test cases for three functions that are not returning any values but they expect two numeric values?

How can I test these functions? Can somebody help me, please

```
const app = function () {
  let buttons = numbers;
  for (let i = 1; i <= buttons.length; i++) {
    Buttons(buttons, i);
  }
};

const Buttons = (buttons, i) => {
  let div = document.getElementById("main");
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  let text = document.createTextNode(i);
  button.id = "btn-" + i;
  button.appendChild(text);
  div.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let num = text.nodeValue;
    for (var i = 1; i <= buttons.length; i++) {
      Highlight(num, i);
    }
  });
};


const Highlight = (num, i) => {
  if (i % num === 0) {
    let box = document.getElementById("btn-" + i);
    box.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    let box = document.getElementById("btn-" + i);
    box.classList.remove("active");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test them by testing theirs side effects by mocking and spy calls of external methods

- `document.getElementById`
- `box.classList.add`
- `box.classList.remove`
- `button.addEventListener`
- `document.createElement`
- `document.createTextNode`

Comment: Hi 8HoLoN, 
Thanks for your reply, could you please share some code sample for that if posible?